# How to check consecutive same value and count of value occur same time pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

In dataframe column B check which value occurs consecutive same and how many times have same value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,11,11,11,11,11,15,16,16]})

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'value':[11],
                 'values count':[5]})
```

Comment: Why 16 isn't considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get only consecutive groups by fir not equal and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with cumulative sum, get all duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and last count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = (df[df.B.ne(df.B.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)]
          .groupby(df['B'].rename('value'))
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   value  count
0     11      5
```

**Details**:

```
print (df[df.B.ne(df.B.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)])
    A   B
4   8  11
5  11  11
6   1  11
7  15  11
8  20  11
```

Or use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for counts:

```
df2 = (df.loc[df.B.ne(df.B.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False), 'B']
          .value_counts()
          .rename_axis('value')
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df2)
   value  count
0     11      5
```

---

It seems input data was changed after edit, so last `16` create new group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,11,11,11,11,11,15,16,16]})
                  
df1 = (df[df.B.ne(df.B.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False)]
          .groupby(df['B'].rename('value'))
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
   value  count
0     11      5
1     16      2
```